# How to save upload image to directory in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

i have a function to upload images , this upload type is json . 
this json like this :

```
"pertanyaan" => "{"question1":"Kondisi, kebersihan, pelumasan bearing","answer1":"baik","image":"gambar.png"} ◀"
```

on this json have a key value = image : gambar.png .
this name of image is saved into json .
and the problem is i cant saved this image (gambar.png) into directory file on folder .
my input:

```
<td> <input class="form-control" style="border:none"  type="file" name="image" value="" readonly> </td>
```

its my controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if($request->hasfile('image'))
     {

        foreach($request->file('image') as $file)
        {
            $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);  
            $data = $name;  
        }
     }

    $user = new pemeliharaan;
    $id = Auth::user()->id;

    $user->user_id = $id;
    $user->alat_id = $request->alat_id;
    $user->pertanyaan =json_encode($request->except
    (['_token','name','alat_id','status','catatan']));//this image on here
    $user->catatan = $request->catatan;
    $user->status = $request->status;


    $user->save();
    //dd($user);
    return redirect('user/show6')->with('success', 'Data Telah Terinput');

}
```

I am create a folder images at public. can someone correct my code to saved file(image) ?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot upload an image using JSON. Instead you need to use FormData objects. Once you have used FormData objects Laravel will be able to pickup the uploaded file.

Depending on how you are handling the request on your front end, you could handle this in a variety of methods.

You can find [more information about FormData objects here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

Comment: [https://appdividend.com/2018/02/09/laravel-multiple-files-upload-tutorial-example/]  i try this tutorial and saved file with json data . and its work sir

Comment: From what I can see, that article is not uploading data with JSON. It is using a standard HTTP form request.

Comment: i think i miss perception on this topic . i make a function upload like this article. this article saved 'name' file on table db using json .

Comment: on this line sir " $file->filename=json_encode($data);"

Comment: If you JSON encode the uploaded file it will just convert it to a string. On converting to a string it will just use the filename. It won't actually store the file itself. I would advise researching this topic further to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: yes its just save name file to a string sir. ok this topic is clear , in my problem , i cant save this file on my directory folder .